# Write a javascript function count(arr, callback). It should return the number of elements for which the callback(an arrow function) is true

Tags: javascript, callback, arrow-functions

For example:

```js
count([2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8], (e) => e === 2)  // Expected: 2
count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e > 1)          // Expected: 3
```

**It is also necessary to use forEach**

What I have:

```
function count(arr, callback) {
  let values = 0
  arr.forEach(cb ? values++ : values + 0)
  return values
}
```

This doesn't work though. Any advice?

Comment: You have to pass a **function** to `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, `forEach` needs to be passed a function.

```
arr.forEach((item) => { 
...
})
```

Also, your variable `cb` is not defined. Your parameter is called `callback`

I have updated your example with these changes:

```
function count(arr, callback) {
  let values = 0
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    callback(item) ? values++ : values + 0
  })

  return values
}
```

Comment: If an answer has helped you, you should 'accept' it; This will mark your question as solved, and also reward both you and the answerer some reputation - [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
const count = (array, callback) => array.filter(callback).length
```